# What does it mean when there are two treble clefs in the same piece?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

What am I supposed to do in the first 12 bars?
See below for the piece.
[image]

Comment: see this question for the answer: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41352/piano-grand-staff-with-two-treble-clefs-where-to-place-hands

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the bottom stave in each pair is played with r.h. Those are the notes to play. BUT - they're all played with l.h. as it's the bottom stave. Reason is simple. Those notes could be written in bass clef(F clef), but they'd all be on leger lines, and be a little more tricky to read.

It could all have been written in the 'normal' way,but an octave lower, with '8va' included,to sound the same, and be as easy/difficult to play.

This question may disappear as very similar ones already exist.